# Why i can't go on the route of the child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

I have the following project structure: `GalleryModuleModule` there is a parent component `GalleryComponent` in which there are two child components: `GalleryAddComponent` and `GalleryItemComponent`. When I want to switch from the component `GalleryComponent` to the component `GalleryAddComponent` the address in the address bar changes, but the parent component does not disappear and the transition to the child component does not occur. Help to understand what the problem is and how to solve this problem.

**GalleryRoutingModule:**

```js
const galleryRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'gallery',
        component: GalleryComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'gallery-add', component: GalleryAddComponent},
            {path: 'galleryItem/:id', component: GalleryItemComponent},
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(galleryRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

**template of GalleryComponent:**

```js
                <a routerLink="gallery-add" class="btn btn-outline-success tog">
                    Add New Post
                </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['./galleryItem', pic.id]">
            <img [src]="pic.url" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="lead"><span>{{pic.id}}:</span>{{pic.title}}</p>
        </a>
```

Comment: why have you used ``'./galleryItem'`` ?

Comment: As a child route, `GaleryAddComponent` would usually be added to a `router-outlet` within the `GalleryComponent`. If you want `GalleryComponent` to be replaced, add it to that `children` array, and use an empty path

Comment: when i use 'galleryItem' nothing changes

Comment: @user184994 thx, now i see add and item components  Couldn't you tell me more in detail how to hide "GalleryComponent" when I switch to "GalleryAddComponent" or "GalleryitemComponent"

Comment: @IgorShvets Are you able to create a basic reproduction in StackBlitz? The components don't need to be functional, just the routing. Then I can edit it to show you what I mean

Comment: @user184994 here, please look:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbcvlw

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a different component for holding the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.You can show the `GalleryComponent` there if the path is `''`. From you `GalleryComponent` you can have a link to other two components: `GalleryItemComponent, GalleryAddComponent`. This way, when you click on a link in your gallery component, it will be replaced by the other component.

Created a sample on stackblitz https://angular-hbb4qt.stackblitz.io

Comment: Updated with the stackblitz link

Comment: Thank you, but I need to "GalleryComponent" was the father component, because I in the condition prohibit access to it while in "AppComponent"
here is what i mean (some of my project): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdgqcm

Comment: you can use the same `[canActivate]` guard in the appcomponent